# If/Else Ternary Operator with Blank Else Statement Issue

Tags: php, arrays, ternary-operator

Usually I can get away with using something like:

```
$a = ($condition)? array(1,2,3) : '';
```

But now I have a method that accepts a multidimensional array and I must pass or not pass one of the arrays conditionally.

```
$this->mymethod(
    'myarrays'=> array(
        array('key' => 'lang_code'),
        array('key' => 'lang_description'),
        array('key' => 'lang_direction'),
        ($mycondition==true)? array('key' => 'lang_export') : ),
    )
);
```

Basically, the issue is with the last array passed. And more specifically the ELSE statement in the ternary If operator. It seems that I can't pass simply a blank space after the : and I can't pass anything else like FALSE or '' (empty string), because later on in the code the foreach that runs through this array gives errors.

My question is:
**How to pass a parameter to a function/method based on a condition?**

Comment: What about an empty array instead of null/empty string?

Comment: Hm, is your example valid code anyways?

Comment: You cannot pass an "empty" false statement, I usually use `null`. The only ternary shorthand allowed is `condition ?: val_if_false`, in which case the value of the condition is returned if it does not evaluate to false.

Comment: @user1442158: This doesn't work in my case, because the receiving function does not check for empty arrays. It just goes through all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_filter(array(
    array('key' => 'lang_code'),
    array('key' => 'lang_description'),
    array('key' => 'lang_direction'),
    $mycondition ? array('key' => 'lang_export') : null),
));
```

This will remove the `null`

Comment: Indeed, passing null as the ELSE statement and running the resulting array through array_filter() did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @bažmegakapa, why is this not suitable for production?

Comment: @user190284 Because the guy who will maintain your code (can be your future self) will spend minutes over this statement. Of course it's cool, and you will feel like a hacker when you write it, but it won't look that fun later.

Comment: @bažmegakapa You have really problems going over this? O_o My future self already found it readable ... :X

Comment: @KingCrunch I have no problem reading it (though it is not comfortable). Others might have. That's the whole point. Just an opinion though, we don't need to agree.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$mycondition? array('key' => 'lang_export') : null
```

Now, you could simply run it through `array_filter(..)`, to remove that `NULL` element.

Comment: Why would you ever compare an expression with `true` instead of just using it as is? Plus the parenthesis are obsolete.

Comment: @TobiasSjösten: Correct, it comes from OP's code. I will update my code.

Answer (score 1):

Aim for readability, not for how can you type less. The ternary operator is great because in certain cases it increases readability. This is certainly not that case.

Be nice to the people reading your code later, including yourself.

Here is an example (comments are the thoughts of the future reader):

```
//OK, so here we have an array
$array = array(
    array('key' => 'lang_code'),
    array('key' => 'lang_description'),
    array('key' => 'lang_direction'),
);

//So the array can have one more element based on this condition
if ($mycondition) {
     $array[] = array('key' => 'lang_export');
}

//And then we pass this array to the method
$this->mymethod(array('myarrays' => $array));
```

You are free to use variables and don't have to write all your code in one statement (well, I must admit I thought that was cool earlier).

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate the condition before the function call, e.g. with a helper-function:

```
function evaluate_condition (array $mandatory, array $optional, $condition) {
    if (true === $condition) {
        $mandatory[] = $optional;
    }
    return $mandatory;
}

$this->mymethod(
    'myarrays'=> $this->evaluate_condition(
        array(
            array('key' => 'lang_code'),
            array('key' => 'lang_description'),
            array('key' => 'lang_direction')
        ),
        array('key' => 'lang_export'),
        $mycondition
    )
);
```